# Как использовать Automapper Collection для вложенных коллекций?

Tags: c#, automapper

Использую `AutoMapper.Collection` **3.1.2** (и `AutoMapper` **6.0.2**)

`A` и `B` из ORM, просто пересоздавать в них коллекции нельзя. Собственно, для этого и нужен `AutoMapper.Collection`.

Маппинг строю по инструкции с главной страницы на гитхабе `AutoMapper.Collection` где написано просто мапить `Mapper.Map<OrderDTO[],Order[]>(orderDtos, orders);` пытаюсь сделать так же, но нифига не работает:

```
  [TestFixture]
  public class UnitTest1
  {
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
      AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
      {
        cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
        cfg.CreateMap<ADto, A>().EqualityComparison((dto, a) => dto.Name == a.Name);
        cfg.CreateMap<BDto, B>().EqualityComparison((dto, b) => dto.Name == b.Name);
      });

      var aDto = new ADto(){Name = "A", Container = new List<BDto>()};
      aDto.Container.Add(new BDto(){Name = "B"});
      var aObj = new A(){ Name = "A" };

      var dtos = new [] {aDto};
      var objs = new [] {aObj};

      AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(dtos, objs);
      Assert.IsNotEmpty(aObj.Container);
    }
  }

  public class ADto
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BDto> Container { get; set; }
  }

  public class BDto
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class A
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<B> Container { get; set; }

    public A() { this.Container = new List<B>(); }
  }

  public class B
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Т.е. есть `ADto` с именем "А" и есть `A` объект с таким же именем. Маппер должен вроде сообразить, что это один и тот же объект (зачем иначе указывать `EqualityComparison`?) и синхронизировать их коллекции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Setter в `A.Container` - он нужен.

   ```
   [Test]
   public void TestMethod1()
   {
     Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
     {
       cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
       cfg.CreateMap<ADto, A>().PreserveReferences();
       cfg.CreateMap<BDto, B>().EqualityComparison((dto, b) => dto.Name == b.Name).PreserveReferences();
     });

     var aDto1 = new ADto { Name = "A1", Container = new List<BDto> { new BDto { Name = "B1" } } };

     var dtos = new[] { aDto1 };
     var objs = new List<A>();

     Mapper.Map(dtos, objs);
     Assert.AreEqual("A1", objs.First().Name);
     Assert.IsNotEmpty(objs.First().Container);
   }
   ```

Comment: Но объект A - вне зоны ответственности маппера. Именно это заявляет Automapper.Collection - я не буду трогать ваши коллекции, я только изменю их состав. Собственно, мне очень нежелательно давать возможность менять коллекцию - ORM на этом навернётся.

Comment: @Monk, можете так же посмотреть как они сами мапают такие объекты:https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Collection.Tests/MapCollectionWithEqualityTests.cs#L314

Comment: @Monk, да Вы правы на счёт обновления коллекции.

Comment: Может я чего-то не понял. Если у меня есть объект А с коллекцией B, то автомаппер не поможет мне дозаполнить коллекцию B, он сможет только создать новый объект A?

Comment: @Monk, судя по тем тестам что я вижу - да. Посмотрите, я обновил ответ. Но он всё равно работает только когда есть публичный сеттер у `A.Container`

Comment: Так, я похоже немного промахнулся с примером кода. Мне хотелось, чтобы маппер соотнёс объекты А и ADto, а коллекции - синхронизировал. Щас поправлю код в шапке.

Comment: @Monk, кстати интересно что если написать вместо `var objs = new List<A>();` -> `var objs = new[] { new A() };` то уже тест не проходит.

Comment: Я вот и не понимаю, должно оно так работать или нет. И если нет, то как синхронизировать коллекцию DTO в коллекцию сущностей из базы. Особенно учитывая то, что у этих сущностей(и их DTO) есть вложенные коллекции.

Comment: Так, в целом, проблема действительно только в сеттере. Спасибо.

Comment: @Monk, так, а при добавлении сеттера, мапер потом не создает новый объект? То есть с Вашей ORM всё правильно работает (На `Container` вызывается просто `Add()`?

Comment: Там всё ещё хуже - он переприсваивает всё таки, но похоже ту же коллекцию, благо ORM молчит. Но рабочий сеттер всё же нужен.